# How to get particular button link in session

Tags: php, jquery, session, foreach

By using foreach loop i got output that i required.
In this case by using foreach loop i will fetched products with name,image,price and button, each button have that particular product link and when i click on button it will redirect to another page with button link because in other page i should use that button link.
In my case because of foreach loop when i click on button i will get button link and stored in session veriable but when this veriable will be used in another page it shows last product button url. So, My query is how to get that particular product link of button when i click on button from foreach loop, and that link will be stored in session veriable that's why we will use this link in any page using session.

Comment: please provide the relevant code.  it will help to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your button storing last id from loop so one solution can be like this

```
foreach($your_array as $element){
// here maybe you have some table to present data or something
// then print all element fields like you do like echo $element['price']...
// so what you can do is in every loop open up form and close it like this
?>
<form action="another_page.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $element['id']; ?>">
    //Here you print other input fields
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Select this">
</form>
<?php
}
```

So on `another_page.php` check if post values are set and simply put id or other data to session

Comment: ya correct my button stored last product link from foreach loop, instead i will get particular link when i click on button is it possible the link stored in session veriable in same page because i use that session veriable in other pages, In this case i dont wan't to reloading the page like above using POST or etc.

Comment: I assume when you say you need to save link in session you mean you need to save link id in session so yes you can do it since in link href you can add likne this `<a href="somepage.php?id=<?php echo $element['id']; ?>"` and in somepage.php get var $_GET['id'] and store it in session